# Adjust the relative positions of Venn diagram using R Venn.diagram package

Tags: r, venn-diagram

I would like to draw a Venn Diagram using the R `Venn.digram` package. Here is my code.

```
library(VennDiagram)
myCol2 <- brewer.pal(3, "Pastel2")

list1 <- c(1:179)
list2 <- c(171:224)
list3 <- c(1:17, 171, 172, 225:230)

venn.diagram(
  x = list(list1, list2, list3),
  category.names = c("list1", "list2", "list3"),
  filename = 'three comparison.png',
  output=TRUE,
  resolution = 600,
  cex = 1.8,  # size of numbers in the cycles
  # sub.fontfamily = "serif",
  fontfamily ="Arial",
  main.fontfamily="serif",
  cat.cex = 1.2, # size of category names
  fill = myCol2
)
```

Here is my Venn diagram output.
[image]

Is there a way to rotate two cycles corresponding to `list2` and `list3` to make the plot look like the following? - Basically, I don't want three centers on the same line.

[image]

Comment: @SamR I updated my post with the example data included.

Comment: The reason it displays like this is because `VennDiagram` does not contain elements that belong to list1 and list2, but does not belong to list3. Are you sure you want to display this combination with non-zero area even though the number of elements is 0? I do not know the `VennDiagram` package, but I've looked through it quickly and I cannot find an option for that. Maybe you should look for some other package that does it? Like `ggvenn`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Dominik Rafacz for introducing the `ggvenn` package. It works.

library(ggvenn)

```
a <- list(list1 = c(1:179),
          list2 = c(171:224),
          list3 = c(1:17, 171, 172, 225:230))

ggvenn(a, c("list1", "list2", "list3"),show_percentage = F)
```

[image]